# a modified version of sigmoid activation function

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I am training a neural network to output agent actions (reinforcement learning). The value range for actions is [0,1], and I want the init value to be 0.05. I am thinking of using some modified version of sigmoid function, same output range, but a bit skewed, the output for 0 is 0.05 (instead of the default 0.5).

As shown in the following drawing, the curve on the right changes sharper (with bigger gradient) compared with the left side.

Any suggestions on how to construct such a function?

[image]

EDIT:
Two possible solutions to this question,

1. piecewise exponential functions, as suggested by @Minus One-Twelfth,
2. piecewise (max) sigmoid functions.

Here are some plots (www.wolframalpha.com) for the four functions,

[image]

Comment: Would you be happy to use a shifted sigmoid function (imagine shifting the graph of the sigmoid function $y =\sigma(x)$ to the right so that it cuts the $y$-axis at $0.05$)?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth, simply shifting the function to the right is a good idea. But the gradient at 0.05 is going to be very small. Is it possible to have sharper increase on the right, but less so on the left?

Comment: You could always try and design your own function. Maybe something piecewise, designed to have some desired properties of the slope and $y$-values. For example combining exponential type curves perhaps.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth yes, good idea, I could have two sigmoid scaled differently and combined at 0 (the gradients from two side would be different). Will try that, thank you:-)  But still wondering if there is such a single function.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thank you so much for your input. Any other suggestions to broaden my view of searching are welcome, even though they might not be directly related to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch of a suggestion:** One possibility for a piecewise function would be to try something like $y = f(x)$ where $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0.05e^{ax}& \text{if } x \le 0 \\
1 - 0.95e^{-bx} & \text{if } x > 0
\end{cases}.
$$
(Essentially using exponentials.)

I have left some constants $a$ and $b$ unspecified; you can experiment with different values for them to see what you want. Note that increasing $a$ will make the curve steeper at $x = 0$. Also, if you want the curve to have equal slope either side of $x =0$, you should choose $a$ and $b$ such that $0.05a = 0.95b$. Best of luck!

Comment: I have another idea, max of two sigmoids, i.e. max(sigmoid(x)*0.1,  sigmoid(x)*1.9-0.9), which is easier to implement. The exponentials (yours suggestion) or sigmoids,  I am not sure which is better, in terms of gradient and training speed.

Answer (score 0):

instead of the classical sigmoid function you could use $$\frac{x-0.965}{\sqrt{0.1+(x-0.965)}}$$
it'll start at 0.05 and be quite a bit sharper

Comment: I plotted this function and it does not seem do what is expected. Could you add a plot for this function? in case I miss anything..